# Laplace Final value theorem proof

Tags: laplace-transform

I was studing FVT and the proof I used was this :
$$\int_0^\infty \hat f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=sF(s)-f(0)$$
$$\lim_{s\to0}\int_0^\infty \hat f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\lim_{s\to0}[sF(s)]-f(0)$$
$$\int_0^\infty \hat f(t)\,dt=\lim_{s\to0}[sF(s)]-f(0)$$
$$f(\infty)-f(0)=\lim_{s\to0}[sF(s)]-f(0)$$
$$f(\infty)=\lim_{s\to0}[sF(s)]$$
it looks straightforward, but i've heard about a condition :  " The standard assumptions for the final value theorem require that the Laplace transform have all of its poles either in the open-left-half plane (OLHP) or at the origin, with at most a single pole at the origin. In this case, the time function has a finite limit."
**now i'm just wondering regarding  the proof where does this come from ? why is this condition needed? What is the reason behind it ?**

Comment: If this was from a book or a pdf, can you say what the source was?

Comment: It is from  Signals and systems by Alan V. Oppenheim and this proof is widely used like [here](https://www.electrical4u.com/final-value-theorem-of-laplace-transform/) and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/final-value-theorem-of-laplace-transform)

Comment: I don't know the specific answer to this issue, but they must be conditions that show that the limits exist. If all limits exist, then your proof is certainly right.